# Dynamically use a structure in c

Tags: c, struct, macros

In my code there are multiple structures like structure_1, structure_2, structure_3 etc. I am trying to write a macro which will enable me to select the correct structure (which structure to select is based on another value). I can't reveal the exact code...but its similar to this

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define concat(X,Y)     X##_##Y
#define typename(X){\
    if(val==0)\
        concat(X,1)\
    else\
        concat(X,2)\
}

int val;

typedef struct  {
    int x;
    char c;
}structure_1;

typedef struct  {
    int y;
    char c;
}structure_2;

int main()  {
    val = 0;
    typename(structure) abc;
    abc.x = 0;
    printf("%d\n",abc.x);
}
```

This doesn't work and is giving issues

```
24  11  E:\DEV\concat.c [Error] expected expression before 'structure_1'
3   22  E:\DEV\concat.c [Note] in definition of macro 'concat'
24  2   E:\DEV\concat.c [Note] in expansion of macro 'typename'
25  2   E:\DEV\concat.c [Error] 'abc' undeclared (first use in this function)
25  2   E:\DEV\concat.c [Note] each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

Using if-else statement is an option, but it'll have to be done for many structures and in many places, so i want to avoid that. Please suggest what i am doing wrong or any other way of doing it.

Comment: Preprocessors including `#define` are processed at compile time, so they do not know the value of `val`, which is decided at runtime.

Comment: Perhaps what you're looking for is a [*tagged union*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union)?

Comment: You can't use an `if` statement in a type declaration.

Comment: Do you want to dynamically declare a variable of one of your possible structure type or dynamically use a variable by re interpreting (ie casting) its type? If your structure do not have any common parameters I do not see what part of the code you can hope to factoryze this way (ie if all structures are different, accessing their content will always be specific code even if you create a "helper" macro)

Comment: I want to dynamically declare a variable of one of the possible structure type. The structures do have fields in common and what i am working on has to do with only those common fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your macro doesn't work is because it results in `if (val == 0) structure_1;` which won't compile because you haven't declared a variable. The `abc` part isn't injected into the macro, so it only appears at the end of the processed macro expansion: `abc` only gets declared as a variable of `structure_2`.

This is easily enough fixed: you have to have the variable name as a parameter to your macro as well. Do that and... now the very point has obviously become ruined because your variables exist only inside the if-else blocks which is what you didn't want.

It's at this point that it should become obvious that this simply isn't how C works fundamentally. Genericism isn't well supported, which is a good thing because genericism isn't relevant to what C is trying to accomplish as a language. You should ask yourself why you are trying to force the language to behave this way. What is the point of what you are trying to do?

Regardless, there is a way to get around this in some sense: Unions. Unions allow you to essentially smack different types together into one type. This has the distinct drawback of forcing variables declared from a union to always be the size of the largest type. If you make a union from a 1-byte char and a 100-byte struct, every variable declared will always consume 100-bytes. On the other hand, if you are smacking together same-sized structs, there is no particular penalty.

A simple demonstration:

```
struct t {
    union {
        int x; float y;
    };
};
int main() {
    struct t a = {0};
    printf("%d\n", a.x);
    printf("%d\n", a.y);
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(a)); // 4
    return 0;
}
```